# Open project folder with Nerdtree and cd into it

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

I have `let g:NERDTreeChDirMode=3` and expect `nvim ~/Projects/foo` to run nvim with `:pwd` set to `~/Projects/foo`. But instead it has `:pwd` set to my home directory from which I am running it. As a result when I g<kbd>o</kbd> to file in NERDTree view, file content replaces NERDTree view, and if I then do NERDTreeToggle, it has root in the home directory instead of project directory.

Is it possible to pass directory to Vim and automatically cd into it and has NERDTree root there ?

**EDIT**: https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Shell: `(cd ~/Projects/foo && nvim)` aka `pushd ~/Projects/foo && nvim && popd`
- As arguments: `nvim +'cd $HOME/Projects/foo'` (you can use `'execute "cd" expand("~/Projects/foo")'` too but that's more verbose IMO)
- Depending on how your shell quotes and expands, you might be able to do `nvim +'cd '~/Projects/foo` (if the path doesn't have any spaces in it on shells that care about that)

If you want something more automatic, you'll need to write an autocommand (probably on `VimEnter`) to check the number of arguments and `:cd` to (e.g.) the first one.

Comment: Not quite what I've expected, but thanks for information)